# BE shortcut to content element TYPO3 6.2

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I can't create a shortcut link to another page width an anchor to a content element in TYPO3 6.2.

In TYPO3 4.5 we can add a shortcut page in the page tree to another page and a content element (on this page). In the menu this look like "www.site.com.ua/yourpage/#c_255" for example. In TYPO3 6.2, I can only find "Shortcut to page", but no content element to chose from. Do I need to activate this function in BE?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is **not possible at the moment**. But there is an open issue in the [TYPO3 tracker](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/46138). It has been created 2 years ago, but the target version for the fix is set to version 7.5. So maybe this feature will be added somewhen.